# Nodejs asynchronous recursive folder size

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, closures, currying

Hi i am pretty new to Javascript, Nodejs and its asynchronous world and i am trying to get the size of a list of folders (like du command) in an asynchronous way. Something like:

```
du = function(directory, callback){
    ...
}

displaySum = function(err, result) {
    if(!err) {console.log(result);}
}

var folders = ['/folder1', '/folder2', '/folder3'];
for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
   du(folders[i], displaySum);
}
```

What i am expecting is to get result from the callback in an asyinch way so when `du` finish for folderN the callback print out the result for folderN.

I tried with this code from [here](http://procbits.com/2011/10/29/a-node-js-experiment-thinking-asynchronously-recursion-calculate-file-size-directory) that uses currying and closures:

```
//Pseudocode
duAsync4 = (dir,cb) ->
    total = 0
    file_counter = 1 #starts at one because of the initial directory
    async_running = 0

    again = (current_dir) ->
       fs.lstat current_dir, (err, stat) ->
           if err then file_counter--; return
           if stat.isFile()
               file_counter--
               total += stat.size
           else if stat.isDirectory()
               file_counter--
               async_running++
               fs.readdir current_dir, (err,files) ->
                   async_running--
                   if err then return #console.log err.message
                   file_counter += files.length
                   for file in files
                       again path.join(current_dir, file)
           else
               file_counter--
           if file_counter is 0 and async_running is 0
               cb(null, total)

again dir
```

The problem i got with this code that uses **Closures** is that if the second call to `du` starts when the first call is still in progress, everything is messed up because the Closure re-use the current values for total, file_counter and async_running.

Comment: Thank you for your answers using Promise but first i would like to understand the basic concepts of asynchronous nodejs (using callbacks) and then use an andvaced library such as Promise or Asynch.

Answer (score 2):

I find callbacks bit cumbersome, so using `Promise` it is still asynchronous, hope the comments clarify things...

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path');

function getSize(dirPath){      
  return getStat(dirPath).then(function(stat){  
    if(stat.isFile()){  // if file return size directly
      return stat.size;
    }else{
      return getFiles(dirPath).then(function(files){    // getting list of inner files
        var promises = files.map(function(file){
          return path.join(dirPath, file);  
        }).map(getSize);    // recursively getting size of each file
        return Promise.all(promises);   
      }).then(function(childElementSizes){  // success callback once all the promise are fullfiled i. e size is collected 
          var dirSize = 0;
          childElementSizes.forEach(function(size){ // iterate through array and sum things
              dirSize+=size;
          });
          return dirSize;
      });
    }    
  });
}

// promisified get stats method
function getStat(filePath){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    fs.lstat(filePath, function(err, stat){
      if(err) return reject(err);
      resolve(stat);
    });
  });
}

// promisified get files method
function getFiles(dir){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, stat){
      if(err) return reject(err);
      resolve(stat);
    });
  });  
}

// example usage
getSize('example dir').then(function(size){
    console.log('dir size: ', size);
}).catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think you must learn before how to deal with multiple asynchronous operations you must look for Promise or a library like async js.

Next you can try something like this:

```js
var fs = require('mz/fs');

var myDir = './';

readdir(myDir)
function readdir(dir) {
  fs.readdir(dir)
    //mz fs transform all fs functions to promises
    .then(function(files) {

    //wait each promises
    return Promise.all(
      files.map(function(file) {

        return fs.lstat(file)
          .then(function(stats) {

            //the function is recursive
            if (stats.isDirectory())
              return readdir(file);
          });
      })
    )
  });
}
```

With this code you can recursively lookup for each sub directory